# Access can't save number and record

Tags: oracle, ms-access, oracle11g, odbc

I've have a problem. I created form to insert and edit data which store in Oracle database 11g.
Firstly , when I want store number (database type NUMBER(9,2) e.g. 12.5, I see message error.

> [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01722; incorrect number [#1722]

Secondly, when I want edit some record Access doesn't save data. I see message about store conflict.
I use Oracle ODBC driver because I have to connect to server via SID.

What do solution for this problems?

Comment: Can you show your query and the data that query is inserting?

Comment: the error message should be *invalid* number, I think - the value that oracle is receiving cannot be converted to a `number(9,2)`. Not sure why, `12.5` *should* be able to be stored in that data type.